# Поддерживают ли TG-боты 3го человека в чате автоматически?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, бот, telegram

(1)

Есть некий бот. Он принимает заказ на, пусть будет, пиццу, опрашивая клиента. Как wizard.
В конце опроса клиент нажимает на кнопку "Да, оформить заказ".

В моём случае необходимо, чтобы в чат с клиентом, после оформления заказа, подключался оператор. Всегда.

До недавней поры у нас это было сделано через посылку приглашения в группу 1-1 c оператом, после приёма заказа. Простыня заказа при этом  отправляется в эту группу.
Но, запарно, неудобно.

(2)

Мне подсказали, что **якобы с недавней поры** ТГ поддерживает 3х (и более?) человек у бота.
То есть, оператору можно сразу пребывать в группе **с ботом и каждым новым клиентом автоматически**, как бы подглядывая за клиентом делающим заказ.

То есть, у оператора будут, скажем, сотни **изолированных, уникальных** чатов с любым **новым** клиентом:
"бот-оператор-клиент"

**Вопрос:**

Такое действительно возможно?
Чаты эти будут уникальные, изолированные?

Как это делается? И как называется?

Comment: Это не то что вам нужно скажу по секрету :)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков заинтригировал! противный

Comment: Оператор и бот - для пользователя "одна сущъность", бот при необходимости транслирует оператору весь чат.( Усложняем - ведем у себя базу "переписок", бот полностью контролирует чат с оператором, при переключении оператора между пользователями бот очищает чат и заполняет историей переписки с новым пользователем). 

Плюсы - к системе можно подключать что угодно (не только телеграмм, и не важно кто что использует при равных возможностях апи. т.е. пользователю телеграмма сможет отвечать оператор из вацапа/почты/сайта/....)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков _бот при необходимости транслирует оператору весь чат_ Зачем очищать чат?   Вопрос, который стоит --> `Как бы извежать технической необхомости приглашать каждого нового пользователя в отдельную группу с оператором, после бота? Как сделать, что оператор уже был в каждом новом чате клиента с ботом автоматически? Поддерживается ли это как мне сказали?` Всё.

Comment: `бот при необходимости транслирует оператору весь чат.` -- ну у нас он это уже и так делает.

Comment: Мне о такой поддержке не известно :) хоть я и слежу за обновлениями бот апи :)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков. Ну, может и не именно так, а что-то похожее. Например, что клиент открывая бота, сразу должен выбрать подбота что-ли,  или подгруппу для общения с ботом. Или копию бота. И в этой под-группе он уже начинает общаться с ботом. И там же, видимо, уже сидит и оператор.  Может такое есть? Я не знаю как оно называется.

Comment: из бот апи мне такое не известно, только из клиентского :)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков а что за "клиентское api"?

Comment: Например вот эта штука на питоне умеет в клиентское(нужен полноценный аккаунт, с номером телефона...) апи https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков тогда я клиентский и использую - pyrogram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Оператор может присоединиться к чату с клиентом после того, как он сделает заказ. Вы можете использовать функцию `Telegram Bot API` под названием «`getUpdates`», чтобы прослушивать новые сообщения и определять, когда клиент разместил заказ. Как только бот обнаружит, что заказ оформлен, он может пригласить оператора присоединиться к чату с покупателем. Есть и другие способы добиться этого, например, с помощью вебхуков.
- Да, в чате `Telegram` с ботом может быть несколько человек. `Telegram` поддерживает групповые чаты, в которых бот может взаимодействовать с несколькими участниками. Бота можно добавить в существующий групповой чат или создать новый групповой чат с оператором и клиентом. Эта функция называется «групповой чат», и ее можно использовать для создания комнаты чата, в которой несколько человек могут одновременно общаться с ботом.
- Оператор может использовать `Telegram Bot API` для мониторинга группового чата и автоматического определения новых клиентов. Также бота можно запрограммировать на уведомление оператора о присоединении нового клиента к групповому чату. Таким образом, оператор может сразу начать общение с клиентом.

Что касается безопасности этих чатов, шифрование `Telegram` гарантирует, что все сообщения, отправленные в чате `Telegram`, являются частными и могут быть прочитаны только предполагаемыми получателями. А что касается названия этой функции, она называется многопользовательский чат или групповой чат.

Comment: (1) через `getUpdates` - оператора должен будет сам вручную туда присоединятся или можно это сделать автоматически? И как?

Comment: Если есть, скажем, 1000 клиентов, которые заказывают пиццу -- у каждого такого "бот-клиент-операт" будет свой уникальный, то есть, изолированный чат на 3 лица (2 человека + бот)?

Comment: Эти чаты могут висеть месяцами? Или они каждый раз будут пересоздаваться?

Comment: (1) «getUpdates» — это метод, предоставляемый Telegram Bot API, который позволяет вам получить список обновлений (сообщений, отправленных пользователями вашему боту), которые произошли с момента последнего вызова метода.

Если вы хотите автоматически присоединить пользователя к определенному чату или группе, вы можете сделать это, отправив сообщение или приглашение пользователю через бота после того, как пользователь отправит сообщение боту с помощью метода getUpdates.

Comment: (2) Это зависит от того, как вы реализовали своего бота и как вы хотите обрабатывать взаимодействие с клиентами.

Если вы хотите, чтобы у каждого клиента был свой уникальный чат с ботом, то да, у каждого клиента будет свой изолированный чат с ботом, и всего будет 1000 таких чатов.

Однако, если вы хотите обрабатывать все взаимодействия с клиентами в одном чате или группе, вы можете использовать один чат или группу для всех клиентов и бота. В этом случае все клиенты будут отправлять сообщения в один и тот же чат или группу, и бот будет отвечать всем им в одном чате или группе.

Comment: (3) Не понял. Изначально, если, скажем, 5 заказчиков пиццы решат заказать пиццу, у каждого из них будет уникальный, изолированный чат с ботом, 1-1? Или они как все в 5ом окажутся в одном чате?

Comment: (3) API Telegram позволяет поддерживать активные сеансы чата неограниченное время, поэтому чаты могут зависать сколько угодно долго, даже месяцами. Однако, если вы хотите каждый раз воссоздавать чаты, вы тоже можете это сделать.

Когда вы получаете сообщение от клиента, вы можете проверить, существует ли уже сеанс чата с клиентом. Если это так, вы можете продолжить разговор с клиентом в существующем чате. Если это не так, вы можете создать новый сеанс чата с клиентом.

Comment: У них у всех будут разные чаты смотря как вы этого хотите

Comment: Ладно. Не все ещё понятно. Но, уже что-то понятно

Comment: Почитайте про [API Telegram](https://core.telegram.org/)

Comment: A. Сейчас у нас пользователь-заказчик, после заказа, получает ссылку в группу с оператом. И он туда должне перейти. Но, можно ведь делать и наоборот - приглашать оператора в чат, после заказа. Правильно? Тогда пользователю никуда не нужно нажимать, переходить...

Comment: Да это смотря на ваше усмотрения